# I have scrambled the earth’s landmasses to form the world of Htrea

Tags: climate, earth-like, worldbuilding-process

[image]There are still mountains in the same spots of their mother continents. Wind directions, orbit, and water temperatures are all exactly that of Earth’s (as well as planet size). The equator runs straight thru the middle of the graphic. Can anybody help with tell me what climates would form in this world? I need this information so I can start writing the history, but I’m clueless when it comes to climate zones unfortunately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What projection does that map use -- is it supposed to be a cylindrical projection covering 360° of longitude and 180° of latitude? (And the shapes and sizes of the continents are very different from those on Earth -- you cannot pick a map and move or rotate continents while hoping to preserve their shapes and sizes, because Earth is not actually flat like a sheet of paper.)

Comment: This is a Mercator Projection, and yes all the landmasses are not going to be the same sizes as the real world. As you can see Antarctica over by the “Turkey” region is very small.

Comment: There is no land at the top or bottom of the Htrea also.

Comment: well with no polar land masses it will be both warmer and over the long run more volatile.

Comment: Where are New Zealand and Japan? Looks fun. Edit: found Japan. I think New Zealand fell off the planet though?

Comment: Nice planet name :p

Comment: Hi Dominic. Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Climate is *incredibly* complex and a question this broad is inappropriate for this stack. Further, we help people develop and consistently use the rules of a fictional world of their own creation. What's stopping you from placing biomes where you want them?

Comment: I want the climates to be realistic, how they would really be if the earths land were arranged in this form, that’s all

Comment: Pointless nitpick question: how did Australia get bigger than the entirety of South America?

Comment: Jokes apart, asking about how would the climates would form in your entire world seems a little too broad for the SE's usual scope, especially since a similar amount of content on every climate on earth can easily fit a book.

Comment: Seriously, though, *how* did you do this? Is there a website for this or something?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if winds, water temperatures (and I assume currents) and planet size and temperature are all the same as Earth's, you could start by establishing and outlining the main climates :
[image: Earth climates]

Usually, as a rule of thumb, you will find tropical forest on the equator, and arid areas or deserts around the tropics, then temperate climates over the north tropic and under the south one. The rest would depend on the topography I would say, but I'm far from an expert. If topography is also the same as Earth's, you could work on the biomes and vegetation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biome#/media/File:Vegetation.png

Hope that helps

Comment: You tend to get deserts in the 30s (N and S) of latitude and high winds in the 40s, due to the Earth's Hadley cells. If the Mediterranean Inlet is at 35 deg N, you'll have less desert than if its further north or south.

Comment: A link, because for some reason this worldbuilding forum seems to be full of people who jump on any mention of most of the worlds deserts lying in a (wobbly) band: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadley_cell

Comment: Thank you much, this is certainly a great start

Comment: Thank you for the link Sean, it'll certainly help myself too!